# Division is not being performed on Aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have problem in this query

```sql
select SUM(stock),
       SUM(Req_Stock),
       (SUM(Req_Stock)-SUM(stock))/SUM(stock) 
  from #mapo Join #capo 
     on #mapo.Wk_Num=#capo.Wk_Num
```

Comment: yes, i have some thing like this sum  of stock as 312469 and sum of Req_stock is 117054, so the result of column3 should be some thing like this -0.6253900386918382

Comment: Even i tried this way select Cast((117054-312469)/312469 * 100 as decimal(18,2))  still i am getting 0.00

Comment: thanks peter for taking time for answering my qstn

Answer (score 2):

Multiply one of the elements by 1.0 to force SQL Server to not treat everything as integers.  Your cast isn't working because your are casting it AFTER the division.  Something like `SUM(Req_Stock * 1.0)` should work.

Comment: +1 for the _elegant_ cast via `* 1.0`.  I use that trick all the time and love it.

Answer (score 1):

If the columns are integer fields, then it won't give you a decimal value with division.

To get the decimal value, you have to cast the numerator and demoninator to floats and then divide the result:

```
select SUM(stock), 
       SUM(Req_Stock),
       CAST((SUM(Req_Stock) - SUM(stock)) AS Float) / CAST(SUM(stock) AS Float)
    from #mapo Join #capo
       on #mapo.Wk_Num = #capo.Wk_Num;`
```